# Fixing error "function array_length(bigint[]) does not exist"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a recursive query, encapsulated within a function, that returns a hierarchical survey "structure":

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_survey_results(IN v_survey_id integer DEFAULT 1, IN v_survey_session_id integer DEFAULT NULL)
  RETURNS TABLE(sort_order bigint[], survey_question_id integer, question_text text, required_ind smallint, survey_session_id integer, custom_text text, option_value integer, survey_scale_id integer, survey_scale_type_id integer, parent_survey_question_id integer, parent_survey_scale_option_id integer) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
        WITH RECURSIVE Survey_Structure (PATH, survey_question_id, question_text,
            required_ind, survey_session_id, custom_text,
            option_value, survey_scale_id, survey_scale_type_id,
            parent_survey_question_id, parent_survey_scale_option_id, CYCLE)
        AS (
            SELECT ARRAY[row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Survey_Question.sort_order)], Survey_Question.survey_question_id, Survey_Question.question_text, 
                Survey_Question.required_ind, Survey_Response.survey_session_id, Survey_Response.custom_text,
                Survey_Scale_Option.option_value, Survey_Question.survey_scale_id, Survey_Scale.survey_scale_type_id,
                0 as parent_survey_question_id, 0 AS parent_survey_scale_option_id, FALSE
            FROM ...etc...
```

I can pass a survey_id to this function (`SELECT * FROM get_survey_results(1)`) and it returns all the questions and answers for that survey.

I wanted to determine the "level" of a node within the hierarchy by using:

```
SELECT question_text, array_length(sort_order) AS level,
    ...etc...
FROM get_survey_results(1)
```

My query returns the error

> function array_length(bigint[]) does not exist

The [PostgreSQL array documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html) promises that arrar_length() will handle "anyarray".

What am I doing wrong? Is there an optional package I need to install?

Comment: Depending on your system, there's also a chance you need `array_upper` (that worked for me). https://groups.google.com/a/greenplum.org/forum/#!topic/gpdb-users/Dd3AQV3Zvmk

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Closer examination of the documentation shows that `array_length()` takes *two* parameters.

I just had to change

`SELECT question_text, array_length(sort_order) AS level, ...`

to

`SELECT question_text, array_length(sort_order, 1) AS level, ...`

Comment: There's discussion of adding the shorthand version on the mailing list at the moment. Feel free to weigh in.

Comment: what could be simpler than to give here the explanations that you managed to find ?!
`array_length(anyarray, int)` returns `int` returns the length of the requested array dimension. example `array_length(array[1,2,3], 1)` expect `3`